# Update only Time in a mysql DateTime field

Tags: sql, mysql

How can I update only the time in an already existing DateTime field in MySQL? I want the date to stay the same.

Comment: I tried this, but with no luck:
UPDATE `Entry` SET entry_period_end_date = ADDTIME(entry_period_end_date, INTERVAL 6 Hour) WHERE TIME(entry_period_end_date) = '06:00:00';

Answer (score 77):

Try this:

```
UPDATE yourtable 
SET yourcolumn = concat(date(yourcolumn), ' 21:00:00')
WHERE Id = yourid;
```

Comment: @user666 Except it looks like jp gave the same answer a year earlier, so imo jp's answer should be accepted.  (This is all very old though, Martin probably gave up before any of the correct answers were added.)

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
UPDATE t1 SET DateTimeField = CONCAT(DATE(DateTimeField),' 12:34:56');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myDateTime = ADDTIME(DATE(myDateTime), @myTimeSpan)
WHERE id = @id;
```

Documented on MySQl date functions [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: SET date= ADDTIME(DATE(date), '02:00:00.999998') Sets the date to '0000-00-00 00:00:'

Comment: Seems like a better answer than the higher voted ones because it doesn't rely on string formatting.

Answer (score 5):

I have solved in this way:

```
UPDATE table
SET myDateTime = CONCAT_WS(' ',DATE(myDateTime), CURTIME())
WHERE id = @id;
```

Obviously you should change `CURTIME()` with your desired time.

Comment: This is very helpful, I was searching this statement for sometime on the net. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UPDATE sms 
SET entry_period_end_date= entry_period_end_date+INTERVAL 6 Hour 
WHERE TIME(entry_period_end_date) = '06:00:00';
```

Answer (score 2):

This what helped me. I convert time to minutes firstly: 150 for 2:30 am.

```
UPDATE lesson SET starts_at = DATE_ADD(Date(starts_at), INTERVAL 150 MINUTE)
```

Minutes are enough accurate for me, though you can use other units: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myDateTime = ADDTIME(myDateTime, @myTimeSpan)
WHERE id = @id;
```

For exact syntax of function, see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime).

Comment: The `ADDTIME` function adds a time to the the existing. This means that for this to work, you expect `myDateTime` to be have only the date portion set (and time portion is midnight).

Answer (score 1):

MySQL DEV page shows functions like `subtime` and `difftime`

A sample code to back the time all posts in 3 hours is above:

```
UPDATE tablepost SET datepost = SUBTIME( datepost , '0 3:0:0' );
```

Note that values 0 dont alter the respective field. Take care this code, use select first to test these function.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `table`
SET time = ADDTIME(time, INTERVAL 13 Hour);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, exactly what you are asking for is not possible. The date and time components can't be updated separately, so you have to calculate the new DateTime value from the existing one so that you can replace the whole value.

Comment: Well it is possible to do it, not specifically targeting the time portion of the datetime field, but you can do something to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you have a DATE field and TIME field and want to inject the time into the date, try this:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mydatefield = ADDTIME( DATE_FORMAT(mydatefield,'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'), mydatefield)
WHERE myid = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I used **ADDTIME** in the following way

Earlier in my cloud server, the DateTime was set to UTC but after changing the DateTime to Asia/Kolkata ie UTC 5:30 I wanted the same to reflect in my database tables.

I wanted to update the created_at and updated_at column by 5 hours 30 minutes. I did the following

**To update all the rows of the table**

```
UPDATE 
    products 
SET 
    created_at = ADDTIME(created_at, '5:30:0'), 
    updated_at = ADDTIME(updated_at, '5:30:0')
```

**You can omit the WHERE condition if you want to update all the records, but since my new records were updated with proper values. So only my rows below id less than 2500 must be updated**

```
UPDATE 
    products 
SET 
    created_at = ADDTIME(created_at, '5:30:0'), 
    updated_at = ADDTIME(updated_at, '5:30:0') 
WHERE
    id < 2500;
```