# MySQL modify datetime set hours and minutes without modifying month, year, and day

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a DateTime column and I would like to modify the hours and minutes without touching anything else. I can't just add an interval b/c the values all differ.

e.g

```
*************************************************
** What I've got       *|* What I want         **
************************|************************
** 2012-10-01 10:01:01 *|* 2012-10-01 23:59:59 **
** 2012-08-03 13:09:01 *|* 2012-08-03 23:59:59 **
** 2012-05-10 09:00:01 *|* 2012-05-10 23:59:59 **
** 2012-03-20 20:01:01 *|* 2012-03-20 23:59:59 **
*************************************************
```

Is there a way to do this from a query without having to involve another programming language?

Comment: you may like to check this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326548/update-only-time-in-a-mysql-datetime-field

Comment: @dom ashamed to say I **did** search but didn't find that... Guess my powers of wording my question are weak. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can do this rather easily:

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname = CONCAT_WS(' ', DATE(columname), '23:59:59')
```

Comment: me either on the `CONCAT_WS` woot!

Comment: It's not really necessary in this case, since you can just put the space in the second argument, like doublesharp's answer.

Comment: True, not necessary at all.  I really used it to demonstrate that there can be a one-to-one replacement of the time component using the CONCAT -like statments.  Probably more dummy proof as well, in that adding the leading space before the time component could easily be missed.  Could have also done `CONCAT(DATE(columnname), ' ', '23:59:59')`

Comment: ... or just CONCAT(DATE(columnname), ' 23:59:59'), but that would be nitpicky. Anyways. Thanks! This was exaclty what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

You can just set the `date_column` to a string after extracting the current `DATE()` value of the column.

```
UPDATE `table` SET `date_column` = CONCAT(DATE(`date_column`), ' 23:59:59')
```